# Dropdown to fetch value from an adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have set up a dropdown in a new sheet (using a Named Range) to pull the values from Column B in 'Control Sheet #1', as shown below:

```
|   ID   |   Desc   |
|--------|----------|
| 1xc2   | Object   |
| 54hh   | Variable |
| 86fc   | Name     |
```

How can I pull the adjacent value from the 'ID' column into the new sheet?. E.g. if I were to select *Object* with the dropdown, the ID shown beside the dropdown should be *1xc2*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dropdown is in D1 then put this in E1.

```
=iferror(index('Control Sheet #1'!a:a, match(D1, 'Control Sheet #1'!b:b, 0)), "")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! But is there a way to make the value in E1 refresh every time the dropdown selection is changed?

Comment: Turn your Formulas, Calculation to Automatic.

Comment: Perfect, awesome stuff!